# find class name of html source using php

Tags: php, parsing, xpath

I am new to PHP. I want to write code to find the `id` specified in the html code below, which is `1123`. Can any one give me some idea?

```
<span class="miniprofile-container /companies/1123?miniprofile="
      data-tracking="NUS_CMPY_FOL-nhre"
      data-li-getjs="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=dyt8o4nwtaujeutlgncuqe0dn&amp;fc=2">
    <strong>
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/nus-trk?trkact=viewCompanyProfile&pk=biz-overview-public&pp=1&poster=&uid=5674666402166894592&ut=NUS_UNIU_FOLLOW_CMPY&r=&f=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Fcompany%2F1123%3Ftrk%3DNUS_CMPY_FOL-nhre&urlhash=7qbc">
        Bank of America
        </a>
    </strong>
</span> has a new Project Manager
```

Note: I don't need the content in the span class. I need the `id` in the span class name.

I tried the following:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xmlElements = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$id = $xmlElements->xpath("//span [@class='miniprofile-container /companies/$data_id?miniprofile=']");
```

... but I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Could you please explain what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dependent of your need, you could do

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('|<span class="miniprofile-container /companies/(\d+)\?miniprofile|', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

this is a very trivial regex, but could serve as a first suggestion. If you want to go via DomDocument or simplexml, you mustn't mix both like you did in your example.
What is your preferred way, we can narrow this down then.

//edit: pretty much what @fireeyedboy said, but this is what I just fiddled together:

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOD
<html><head></head>
<body>
<span class="miniprofile-container /companies/1123?miniprofile="
      data-tracking="NUS_CMPY_FOL-nhre"
      data-li-getjs="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=dyt8o4nwtaujeutlgncuqe0dn&amp;fc=2">
    <strong>
        <a href="#">
        Bank of America
        </a>
    </strong>
</span> has a new Project Manager

</body>
</html>
EOD;

$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$domDocument->recover = TRUE;
$domDocument->loadHTML($html);

$xPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$relevantElements = $xPath->query('//span[contains(@class, "miniprofile-container")]');
$foundId = NULL;
foreach($relevantElements as $match) {
    $pregMatches = array();
    if (preg_match('|/companies/(\d+)\?miniprofile|', $match->getAttribute('class'), $pregMatches)) {
        if (isset($pregMatches[1])) {
            $foundId = $pregMatches[1];
            break;
        }
    };
}

echo $foundId;

?>
```

Comment: I used the same code for the following html code to take the id but it is not working...can you please help me...

<script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[ */
 var dbl_src = "http://ad-apac.doubleclick.net/adj/linkedin.dart/" + dbl_page + ";lang=en;tile=1;dcopt=ist;sz=300x250;;" + encodeURIComponent('company=8099') + ";s=0;ord=" + Math.random() * 10000000000000000 +"?";
 document.write('<sc' + 'ript src="' + dbl_src + '" type="text/javascript"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
 /* ]]> */
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are after:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
@$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

/*
 * the following xpath query will find all class attributes of span elements
 * whose class attribute contain the strings " miniprofile-container " and " /companies/"
 */
$nodes = $xpath->query( "//span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' miniprofile-container ') and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' /companies/')]/@class" );
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    // extract the number found between "/companies/" and "?miniprofile" in the node's nodeValue
    preg_match( '#/companies/(\d+)\?miniprofile#', $node->nodeValue, $matches );
    var_dump( $matches[ 1 ] );
}
```